# Syntax Highlighting for WL files in Atom/Sublime?

Tags: packages, interoperability, syntax-highlighting, editing

What packages do people use for syntax highlighting in Atom, Sublime Text 3, etc?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I use [language-mathematica](https://atom.io/packages/language-mathematica) with Atom, it includes function name autocompletion up to 11.0.1 as well as links to the WL reference. There's also [goto-mathematica](https://atom.io/packages/goto-mathematica) by the same author as well as a [plugin](https://atom.io/packages/linter-mathematica) for Linter.

[image]

Comment: I have a question, @Graumagier, can you also run the scripts directly from Atom? I have the package ``script" installed on atom but I cannot run the mathematica scripts with it.

Comment: I never tried it, but since there are similar projects working with iPython/Juypter-style notebooks providing interactivity (and there's WolframScript) that's probably worth a separate question.

Comment: Thank you. I will post the question soon